# Drawing one group over the other in libgdx (same stage)

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a menu screen on my game with two Groups using the same stage: maingroup and popupgroup(hidden -> isVisible(false)). When any button on maingroup is clicked, the popupgroup(isVisible(true)) is then added to the stage and it comes with an Imagebutton.

I would like to darken the entire screen to a certain extent except the ImageButton on display. Also how can I have it such that a click anywhere else on the screen except ImageButton will remove() the popupgroup and bring maingroup to the forefront?

Code..

```
...addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

                maingroup.setTouchable(Touchable.disabled);
                popupgroup.setVisible(true);
                popupgroup.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f);
                popupgroup.addAction(Actions.fadeIn(1f));

                return true;
            }
```

Is there something like a clicklistener that detect when you've pressed out of bounds of a certain group or item?

Thanks

Comment: Create a 1x1 pixel image, then stretch that image to cover the entire screen, make it transparent and as dark/light as you need it. Also, add an onClick event to it, so that you can hide it when if clicked.

Comment: Thanks.Would never have thought of that..Any way I can select your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - why not to create one more stage? It would be easier to have two stages - one for common sprites and second for pop-ups.

Anyway you need to set the z-index of groups and you should use for this `toFront()` and `toBack()` methods

```
    //when need to show popup
    darkenGroup.setVisible(true);
    popupGroup.setVisible(true);

    darkenGroup.toFront();
    popupGroup.toFront();

    //hide them by using just setVisible(false)
    darkenGroup.setVisible(false);
    popupGroup.setVisible(false);
```

---

About creating this darken semi-transparent group consider using @munyul's comment idea - to keep a 1x1px texture and to stretch it - it should be more optimized